# Hide/show multiple elements with multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, textbox

Updated after the hint in comments.

Current [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/QAaHP/1383/)

Is there a way so that I only have to write the script once and use it for multiple ID's?
I currently have 3 checkboxes so I just copied the code 3 times but if I get for example a 100 checkboxes I can't imagine copying this a 100 times would be verry effecient

Current code

Javascript

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById('div_product_1'),
checkBox1 = document.getElementById('product_1');
checkBox1.checked = false;
checkBox1.onchange = function () {
    elem1.style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};
checkBox1.onchange();

var elem2 = document.getElementById('div_product_2'),
checkBox2 = document.getElementById('product_2');
checkBox2.checked = false;
checkBox2.onchange = function () {
    elem2.style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};
checkBox2.onchange();

var elem3 = document.getElementById('div_product_3'),
checkBox3 = document.getElementById('product_3');
checkBox3.checked = false;
checkBox3.onchange = function () {
    elem3.style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
};
checkBox3.onchange();
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product_1" id="product_1" />
<label>Product 1</label><br>
<div id="div_product_1">
    <input type="number" name="quantity_1" id="quantity_1" />

</div>

<input type="checkbox" name="product_2" id="product_2" />
<label>Product 2</label><br>
<div id="div_product_2">
    <input type="number" name="quantity_2" id="quantity_2" />

</div>

<input type="checkbox" name="product_3" id="product_3" />
<label>Product 3</label><br>
<div id="div_product_3">
    <input type="number" name="quantity_3" id="quantity_3" />

</div>
```

Comment: Hint: you have three divs, but only one `elem` variable...

Comment: @nnnnnn OMG thanks, can't believe I missed that..., now I have a second question. Is there a way to write this script only once for every checkbox? I currently have 3 which I can easily copy paste the script for each one individually but imagine if I need 100 how would I solve that?

Comment: Well you could write a loop. But I'd prefer to give the checkboxes a common class and assign one click handler to a parent element, because clicks on each one will "bubble up" to the parent, and you can then code the parent click handler to check whether the clicked element has that class and if so find the associated div and toggle its visibility.

Comment: @nnnnnn Any chance for an example, English isn't my first language and I don't fully understand what you mean. I don't want a solution just an example of what you're trying to tell me so I can understand it.

Comment: A rough but working example: https://jsfiddle.net/QAaHP/1385/ - note that I've wrapped each checkbox/div pair in another div to make it easy to relate them together in JS. Also, I've used CSS rather than JS to make the product divs hidden when the page first loads. (Sorry, I don't have time now for a full explanation of how it works.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Oh wow thanks, I'm figuring it out for myself atm, if you ever get the chance to reply with an explanation it would be much appreciated

Comment: @Steven what's happening is you are saying "any clicks to this document (web page), call this function". the `var cb = e.target` is grabbing the element that was clicked/caused the event. if that element has the `productcheck` class assigned to it (only your checkboxes should) then continue, otherwise leave. if the `if` statement is true, get the parent of the checkbox and then grab the div contained within (the div that contains your input field). then, set the display style of this div based on whether or not the checkbox that triggered this event is checked or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, you are reusing your `elem` variable. Change your code so the second and third `elem` are unique, i.e. [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/QAaHP/1381/)

Comment: Thanks aswell, no clue how I missed it. Do I only need to make the elem unique or do I need to make the checkbox unique aswell. After the hint in the comments i made both the elem and checkbox unique, but I see in your jsfiddle you only made the checkboxes unique?

Comment: Steven, you don't need a unique variable for the checkboxes because (in the code shown) you don't need to refer to the same checkbox again. Whereas the `elem` variable is used every time those click handlers are called. But unique checkbox variables might seem neater...

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try something like this. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oojhwj1y/)
This is mostly so that you don't have to copy paste the whole time.

So in a nutshell, i am adding the html `controls` dynamically and then hooking up the `onchange` event on the `checkboxes`

***HTML***

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

***JS***

```
var max_fields = 100; //maximum input boxes allowed

var $placeholder = $("#placeholder");

// Add html controls
for (var i = 0; i < max_fields; i++) {
    $placeholder.append("<input type='checkbox' name='product_" + i + "' id='product_" + i + "'/>")
        .append("<label>Product " + i + "</label")
        .append("<div id='div_product_" + i + "'></div>");

    var $divProduct = $("#div_product_" + i);
    $divProduct.append("<input type='number' name='quantity_" + i + "' id='quantity_" + i + "' class='hide'  />");
}

// wire the onclick events
$('[id*="product_"]').change(function () {
    console.log($(this));
    var splitId = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]
    console.log({
        id: splitId,
        control: $("#quantity_" + splitId)
    })
    $("#quantity_" + splitId).toggle()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, loops should do. Also, use `class` instead of `id` on your HTML elements.

***Snippet:***

```js
var numProducts=10;
var classNameProduct='product';
var classNameContainerProduct='div_product';
var classNameQuantity='quantity';
var mainContainer=document.body;
function generateMarkup(){
 for(var i=0; i<numProducts; i+=1){
  mainContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<input type="checkbox" name="'+classNameProduct+'" class="'+classNameProduct+'"/><label>Product '+i+'</label><br>');
  mainContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div class="'+classNameContainerProduct+'"><input type="number" name="'+classNameQuantity+'" class="'+classNameQuantity+'"/></div>');
 }
}
function initCheckboxes(){
 var checkboxes=document.querySelectorAll('.'+classNameProduct),containerProducts=document.querySelectorAll('.'+classNameContainerProduct);
 for(var i=0; i<numProducts; i+=1){
  checkboxes[i].checked=false;
  containerProducts[i].style.display='none';
  (function(index){
   checkboxes[index].onchange=function(){ containerProducts[index].style.display=this.checked?'block':'none'; }
  }(i));
 }
}
generateMarkup();
initCheckboxes();
```

Hope this helps.